# Read/Open image from instance of Python io.BufferedReader class

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm struggling to properly open a TIFF image from an instance of Python's `io.BufferedReader` class.  I download the image from a GCS path using the below lib, but I can't open seem to open the image with traditional tools.

```
# returns the <_io.BufferedReader>
file = beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open("<GCS_PATH>", 'r')

from PIL import Image    
img = Image.open(file.read()) <---- Fails with "TypeError: embedded NUL character"

img = Image.open(file.raw) <--- Fails when any operations are performed with "IOError(err)"
```

I am open to other libraries besides PIL.

**UPDATE**

The following also fails:

```
img = Image.open(file)
```

It fails with an IOError, stating `tempfile.tif: Cannot read TIFF header.`

Comment: `img = Image.open(bufferedreader)`

Comment: Ok.  I think there may be an issue with the version of PIL I am using, because when I do that and then proceed with any operation such as `img_array = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)` or `img.show()` I get an error that starts with `tempfile.tif: Cannot read TIFF header.` and end with `raise IOError(err)
IOError: -2`

Comment: `IOError: -2`: Make sure the file exists. `os.path.exists(fpath)`

Comment: Well, I think the file is represented by the instance of io.BufferedReader class that I set to file variable.  This example works with PNG images, so I think this is an issue with the multipage TIFF images

Comment: A `BufferedReader` is for *sequential* input, so if the TIFF code is trying to seek it's going to fail.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, I just looked at the lib internals and I believe there are seek commands.  Would you be able to recommend me to any transformations of io.BufferedReader that I can then pass to Image.open

Comment: You might be able to read the entire file into a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#in-memory-streams) object and use that. Edit: never mind, it looks just as limited as `BufferedReader`.

Comment: perhaps into StringIO?...

Comment: `StringIO` is for text data, `BytesIO` for binary - you want binary. And on second look `BytesIO` really does support seek, so try that.

Comment: `img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.read()))` appears to be working!

Comment: @RyanStack I recommend you add the answer yourself so others can benefit from it : )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap both in a ContextManager so they both get closed properly.

```
with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(file_path, 'r') as file, Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.read())) as multi_page_tiff:
     do_stuff()
```