# Image preprocessing with Dataflow

Tags: python, image-processing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

*Task:* I am to run an ETL job that will  Extract TIFF images from GCS, Transform those images to text with a combination of open source computer vision tools such as OpenCV + Tesseract and ultimately Load the data into BigQuery

*Problem:* I am trying to use Dataflow to perform the ETL job because I have millions of images (each image is a separate file/blob) and I want to scale to hundreds of machines. However, I am running into some problems with Dataflow (which will be described in greater detail below) regarding the best means to download the images.

*Questions:* Ultimately I am trying to determine:

1)  Is dataflow the best solution to do this? Alternatives that I have considered are running a multithreaded job on a large machine. Are there any other alternatives that I should be considering?

2)  If dataflow is the best solution, then how should I specifically handle downloading the millions of images (so that I can run them through a transformation)?

*Technical challenges:*

The following post [Recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423769/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-in-dataflow-pipeline-run-from-datalab) recommends using `beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filepath, 'r')` in a DoFn to download images from GCS.
I've attempted going down this path, using `beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filepath, 'r')`, however, I am having trouble open the images.  That issue is described here: [IO.BufferReader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395564/read-open-image-from-instance-of-python-io-bufferedreader-class).

When using the `DirectRunner` I can download the image files using this client api `from google.cloud import storage` and I can open and pre-process the images no problem.  However, when using the dataflow runner, I am having dependency issues, `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'storage'`.

That being said, **If Dataflow is the best solution, what is the best method to download and process millions of images?**

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the right think. It seems that you ran into two problems:

- With the `io.BufferedReader` issue, you need to add an interface that will allow you to seek into the Tiff file, as you correctly found [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395564/read-open-image-from-instance-of-python-io-bufferedreader-class).
- It seems that the problem with using the `google.cloud.storage` is that the dependency is not available in the Dataflow environment. To add this dependency, check out [Managing Python pipeline dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) in the Beam documentation.

The main idea is that you can run your pipeline with a `--requirements_file reqs.txt` file passed in, listing all the extra dependencies that you'd like to add.